# Increase in unexplained downvotes on (old) questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I recently received a downvote without comment on [a question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324373/higher-infty-categories) *and all of its answers*, which are good independent of the value of my question imo.  I’ve also had [two](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324973/weighted-colimits-as-adjunctions) [other](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325796/amorphous-proper-classes-in-mk) questions receive similar singular downvotes with the (good) answer on the latter question also downvoted.

I had written all this off as unfortunate but necessary byproducts of anonymity, however the [discussion in the comments here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326332/sunflower-delta-system-lemma-in-a-more-general-poset) raised my eyebrows — it seems that this recent phenomenon is not isolated to my posts.

I’m not entirely sure what to propose we do about this, if it is one individual or a small group of them. I agree that anonymity in down voting is essential and it would be burdensome to have to put in an explicit reason each time we downvote, but it seems generally discouraging to the spirit fostered on MO to have unexplained (and apparently unjustified) downvotes unchecked and on the rise.

Comment: Moderators and users with 25k+ reputation can have [access to site analytics](https://mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/site-analytics) where they can see whether there was an increase in number of downvotes. I have created also two simple [SEDE queries](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info) which show number of downvotes [per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1019466/number-of-downvotes-per-month#graph) and [per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1019478/1259127/number-of-downvotes-per-day-between-two-dates#graph).

Comment: When looking at those results, you should keep in mind that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week. Of course, with SEDE one can do also further analysis - if somebody has time to look into that. (For example, it can be checked which users get largest numbers of downvotes, whether there are more downvotes in some tags than others, etc.)

Comment: Much appreciated Martin, looking at those statistics it appears as though things are on par for the recent trends.

Comment: My personal impression is that also number of close votes was recently higher than usual. I don't know a way to count close votes directly, but they are reflected in close vote reviews - here are the numbers [per month](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1019528/1259182/number-of-close-vote-reviews-per-month#graph) and [per day](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1019531/1259185/number-of-close-vote-reviews-per-day#graph). Feel free to [ping me in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2019/3/29) if some other similar stats might be useful.

Comment: Well, I certainly have my strong suspicions who is doing the downvoting on the first, and maybe the third question. It's very likely on the basis of a particular tag, which the user is now scouring looking for things to downvote, in a fit of pique. But since this is speculation, that's all I'll say for now. Just know that we're watching...

Comment: Some unexplained downvotes also appeared in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326150 .

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but I noticed that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1266792/660) of Carl Mummert on MSE got *five* unexplained downvotes. I don't have *the slightest idea* why, and I find this very perplexing. (Perhaps people who, unlike me, know some logic can guess the reason for the downvotes, but even if this reason exists, I find disturbing that none of the downvoters cared to give an explanation.)

Comment: When it seems that some individual or small group has gone on a downvoting spree, my feeling is that the best course of action is to flag one of the downvoted questions or answers for moderator attention, detailing the untoward activity you've spotted. The moderators have the tools to do something about it (if they find merit in your accusations), while there's not much other users can do beyond offering sympathy.

Comment: Your vigilance is much appreciated Todd, I think moderators keeping a finger on the pulse of these things and intervening at their own discretion is probably the best solution. Thank you for the suggestion Gerry, I wasn’t aware I had that recourse and will use it moving forwards.

Comment: And of course thank you @MartinSleziak for the additional statistics, I'll ping you if anything additional occurs to me.

Comment: -1. You take an example of serial downvoting with malicious/trolling intent, and then use it to go on a crusade against *unexplained* downvotes in general. I think that this is a fallacious generalization. The ability to leave downvotes without explanation is on the Stack Exchange network by design. I can understand how you feel, and I am sympathetic, but as it stands, this question is ill-posed.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Your downvotes statistics probably should be normalized to account for changes in traffic. For instance, the downvotes / upvotes ratio would make more sense as a measure, in my opinion.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have tried to make a query with the ratio you suggested: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/revision/1020046/1259834/downvotes-upvotes-ratio-per-month#graph If there is more SEDE related stuff, we can [discuss it in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19138/conversation/recent-downvotes-on-mo). (I suggested chat mainly because I do not want to digress too much in the comments - so that this does not become a discussion about SEDE instead of the original topic.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I’m not sure how we objectively differentiate ‘serial downvoting with malicious/trolling intent’ from giving a bunch of downvotes without explaining them, but I don’t see the above as a ‘crusade’ against either of them. I think anonymous and even unexplained downvotes have a healthy place on MO, but it seems like there’s been a recent negative trend felt by multiple community members so I started this thread as a place to discuss it openly and gain some clarity.

Comment: A few days ago I received an unexplained downvote on an [old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309785/stationarity-and-fodors-lemma-for-a-nice-poset). This actually inspired me to ask [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326332/sunflower-delta-system-lemma-in-a-more-general-poset) in a similar spirit. I promptly received a downvote and a close vote without explanation. All I can say is: if the serial downvoter / close voter is trying to discourage something, I think they'll find their plan backfires. Edit: now I see my situation was already linked in the OP!

Comment: If the problem is perceived to be serious enough to do something about it, then what about the following?: Make downvotes on a post be shown and have an effect on the post score only if there are at least three of them; if there are only one or two downvotes on a post and none are added to them within a certain time, then let them 'age away' by the time like close votes.

Comment: @StefanKohl I like that idea; downvotes are an immediate response to a question prior to a close vote used to express that something is wrong, and if they’re justified others will pick up on it too and downvote as well.  It makes downvotes a more ephemeral form of negative expression by letting them fade with time if not reinforced. I think they should be given a week or more before they age out, but the plan overall seems good.

Comment: I agree with the point of the question, which concerns a multiple number of downvotes, probably by a single user. If one user complains about several downvotes on his own questions, this is a distinct topic, and should be treated separately. Or at least in a separate answer, instead of ten comments here.

Comment: Another (relatively mild) example: Someone has been downvoting, without explanation, a number of recent questions from ar.grig and my answers to those questions. Maybe someone just doesn't approve of ultrafilters.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I recently picked up another unexplained downvote on the first linked question in this post; I think it may have upset some of the anonymous downvoters on MO — so be it, let them have their tantrum ;).

Comment: I would appreciate it if we kept things as civil as possible here; passionate disagreement is natural in any academic discipline, but we’re all mathematicians (a small minority on this rock) — we should circle the wagons and support each other where possible, not weaken ourselves from the inside with insignificant disputes.

Comment: Separating out the pieces that are strictly mathematical and bringing them here is a good practice imo and I look forward to contributions like that, but bringing the whole case here for something that isn't strictly mathematical is generally not (I think) a post that individuals on MO want to spend time reading -- a link to a personal blog in your bio or some such is something I think I've seen on other profiles and is fine, but there's a sharp difference between leaving an avenue open for people to explore your positions and trying to foist your views on other people.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92221/discussion-on-question-by-alec-rhea-increase-in-unexplained-downvotes-on-old-q).